# Textbox and Select list position

Tags: html, css, show-hide

```
Project Name :<div style="position:absolute" id="project_list">
<select style='width:220px;height:25px;' class='createNewSelect' name='list_project_name' id='list_project_name' onchange='javascript:getProjectName()'><option value='0'>Create New Project</option><option value=2>new_project</option><option value=3>new_project</option><option value=5>new_project</option><option value=8>new_project</option><option value=7>my_project_1</option><option value=6>my_project</option></select>


 </div><input id="project_name" class="createNew" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Create New" id="getChecked" class="createNew" />

<button value="Cancel" class="createNew" onclick="cancelCreate()" >Cancel</button>
```

Above use to display project list or textbox with two button to create new project.
I'm facing problem with their position.

[image]

and you can also check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w8z7V/)

[image]

My problem is Textbox and button are not display with `Project Name :` text

Answer (score 1):

Like this just `add` `input{ display:block;}`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w8z7V/1/)**

**css**

```
input{
    display:block;
}
```

---

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/w8z7V/2/)**

**css**

```
#project_list label{
    display:block;
}
#project_list input{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.createNew{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: when user select `Create New Project` textbox should display with two button. Otherwise selectlist will be visible and rest will be hidden. I have problem with their position as you can see on screenshot

Comment: Just check my first screenshot, there button and textbox are showing one after another. I have layout problem